# Re-link a 2gp package to new devhub org

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, dev-hub

I created a managed package which is linked to a dev hub org (developer edition org). It is working fine and I am able to create new versions and all that.
But now I got a new PBO org as I plan to list it on appexchange. And now I want to link my 2GP package to this new org as I will be using this new PBO org as my main devhub org.
Any idea how to do it? I tried deleting namespace registry from old org and [added a Namespace registry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm) to my new PBO org but it didn't work. new PBO org still shows no packages in SFDX cli (when I run this `sfdx force:package:list`)

Comment: Moving to a new dev hub becomes possible only once your orgs migrate to Winter '23 - it has, so far, not been supported.

Comment: thanks. Is there any documentation for this saying it will be in Winter 23?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_packaging_transfer_dev_hub.htm&type=5&release=240), the ability to move a package from one device hub to another is new, as beta, in Winter '23:

> Transfer the ownership of an unlocked or second-generation managed package from one Dev Hub org to another. A transfer can occur internally between two Dev Hub orgs that you own, or you can transfer a package externally to another Salesforce customer, Salesforce Partner, or ISV. This change provides a way to sell an unlocked or second-generation managed package.